# Separating Typeorm Entities from Domain Entities

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, domain-model, orm, typescript

Is it a bad approach to add domain logic inside typeorm entities if following the domain model pattern to organize business logic.

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Column()
    lastName: string

    @Column()
    isActive: boolean

    // .. methods for domain logic here

}
```

Or we should make two separate classes and let the repository map typeorm entity to domain entity and vice versa. If yes, I also want to know what benefits it brings if we separate them. Thanks.

Comment: ... Note I think your question isn't special to typescript or typeorm, it applies to all kind of ORMs. It is also not special to DDD, it arises in  all kinds of domain modeling approaches.